# "invalid session token" error when using RedisCacheAdapter

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I want to switch my production Parse Server from using the in-memory cache layer to Redis. (I'm doing this because I want to scale up by having multiple instances of Parse Server respond to clients, and they all need to share user and role data).

When I test this locally, I find that all user session data is lost, and I get the dreaded "invalid session token" error on clients. Two questions (any insights on either is much appreciated!!):

- How should I migrate session data? I was thinking of having a client detect the "invalid session token" error and force the user to reauthenticate, but curious if there's a sleeker solution to this.
- How does Parse Server remember session data after it restarts? It looks like to me that Parse Server uses an in memory cache, and I don't see where or if this in memory cache is written to disk or recalled.

Comment: Your Parse Server should store all the data in a database, typically  a Mongodb instance, and the session is just a data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse Server stores it's session data in the Session collection in Mongo. My `invalid session token error` was caused by an unrelated issue.